# TeXlive 2011 Pretest - Trouble with Synctex?

Tags: texlive, emacs, auctex, linux, forward-inverse-search

Is anyone else having trouble with synctex in the TeXlive 2011 pretest?  My set-up is Emacs+Auctex+Okular (on Linux). I can't get forward-search/sync to work with TeXlive 2011. (I confirmed that my setup still works with TeXlive 2010.)

**Solution**: **Rewrite the relevant lines in the .emacs file as described here**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898710/emacs-auctex-rewriting-the-okular-make-url-function-to-work-with-new-synctex-fu/6904563#6904563

Comment: There's some infor about SumatraPDF causing issues: http://forums.fofou.org/sumatrapdf/topic?id=2131346. Perhaps the same underlying situation?

Comment: My apologies but IMHO this question is "too localized" in time and doesn't fit in the question and answer format of this site. I strongly recommend to post SW issues, especially about pretests, in the forum or mailing list of that SW.

Comment: @BeSlayed As Martin says, issues with pre-test software are best addressed by mailing the appropriate list.

Comment: OK, thanks. I already posted to the TeXlive mailing list. Posted here in case there was a known work-around.

Comment: @Joseph: Yes, someone else pointed me to the SumatraPDF message, and I think it must be the same problem.

Comment: In case people end up here from web searches, a link to (a) solution has been added in the main body above.